# Python Dataframe:Change values of a column based on another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with two columns `a` and `b`. I want change `NaN` values in column `b`. Eg: For the value of 123 in column `a`, column `b` has both `abc` and `NaN`. I want both to change to `abc`:

```
df
         a        b
0     123       NaN
1     123       abc
2     456       def
3     456       NaN
```

My expected result is:

```
df
        a         b
0     123       abc
1     123       abc
2     456       def
3     456       def
```

Sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = '''\
a,b
123,NaN
123,abc
456,def
456,NaN
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
```

Describing the issue and what i have tried:

```
df.loc[df.a == 123, 'b'] = "abc"
```

Here i'm able to change only for a particular value. i.e., replace `'b'` with `abc` if `'a'` is 123

But for `df.a == 123` and with `'b'` value `NaN` i also wanted it to update `abc`.

So I tried this,

```
df.loc[df.a == NaN, 'b'] = "abc"
```

But, This made all the empty columns in `df` to `abc`.

So, How do i proceed from this?

Edit 2: Sample data 2

```
raw_data = {'a': [123, 123, 456, 456,789], 'b': 
[np.nan,'abc','def',np.nan,np.nan], 'c': 
[np.nan,np.nan,0,np.nan,np.nan]} 

 df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = 
['a', 'b','c'])
```

Ans:

```
 df['b'] = df['a'].map(df.groupby('a')['b'].first()).fillna(df['b'])
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? You could at the very least provide the data in a more convenient format.

Comment: Issue: I have described in above.Please read the question and description. What i have tried: I tried `replace` and `iloc` couldn't succeed. Research : I did with replace and iloc .
Sample data: Updated question with sample data. Any other suggestions @AMC

Comment: _Issue: I have described in above._ No, you described the goal/objective, not a specific problem or obstacle. _What i have tried: I tried replace and iloc couldn't succeed._ Then why not show that?

Comment: Updated with Issue and what i have tried. Any other suggestions @AMC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe first sort your dataframe, then use `ffill`. Something like:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['a','b']).fillna(method='ffill')
```

---

To do this when you have `NaN` values you don't want to overwrite (your "edit2"), you can also use `groupby`:

```
df['b'] = df.sort_values(by=['a','b','c']).groupby('a')['b'].ffill()
```

Comment: When there are multiple columns `ffill` filling the data to other non-empty columns.
Any way to select certain columns for `ffill`

Comment: if another row is there it changing it value too. Added sample data in question

Comment: Found the issue, Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that is using the pandas apply function. It will apply a specific function (here: `my_function`) to a specific column. 
You can change the rules of how to map the values inside my_function. This will allow you to solve more difficult problems.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate some data
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [123, 123, 124, 456, 456], 'B': [np.NaN, 'abc', 'def', 1, np.NaN]})

# define function that maps np.NaN to 'abc'
def my_function(value):
    if value == np.NaN:
        return 'abc'
    else:
        return value

# apply function to column 'B'
df['mapped_B'] = df['B'].apply(my_function)

# check output
df.head()

#   A   B   mapped_B
# 0 123 NaN NaN
# 1 123 abc abc
# 2 124 def def
# 3 456 1   1
# 4 456 NaN NaN
```

Comment: Please use [`np.isnan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) instead of `value == np.NaN` as explained [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/misc.html). Also, with the proposed fix, this would only work for `'abc'`, not for `'def'`. Consider heavily edit this answer.